# taghandler jquery mvc 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i need get data from ajax request for the plugin jquery.tagHandler in my application MVC 3, this is the page official http://ioncache.github.com/Tag-Handler/, and this my code of my app:

```
    $("#tags").tagHandler({
        getData: { texto: 'test 123' },
        getUrl: '@(Url.Action("GetTags"))',
        autocomplete: true,
        maxTags: 5,
        initLoad : true
    });

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetTags(string texto)
    {
        var result = _ServiceTags.Search(texto);

        return Json(result);
    }
```

When arrange my application, this not invoque the method GetTags.

Please help!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: check in firefox web-console that your action gettags is actually being called

Comment: already did, and not show the call to the method GetTags :S

Comment: that menas your url is not correct  getUrl: '@(Url.Action("GetTags"))',

Answer (score 0):

MVC3 has a security feature for JsonResults. You'll need to modify your return to look like:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```